# Values are changed just before being returned

Tags: python-3.x

I have a function which should return a list of tuples.

However the list gets changed just before being returned, and I don't understand why.

The function ends with the two lines you can see below.

```
def calculate_basin(target_point, surrounding_points_coords = [], points_already_checked = [])
...
print("BEFORE RETURNING THE LIST:", surrounding_points_coords)  # line 1
return surrounding_points_coords  #line 2


basin = calculate_basin(target_point = point)
```

When I debug it step by step, I see this:

1. Line 1 is executed. It prints the following:

   BEFORE RETURNING THE VARIABLE: [(0, 1), (0, 0), (1, 0)]
2. the execution point moves to line 2, the return statement.
3. execution point moves back to line 1, but this time it prints this:

   BEFORE RETURNING THE VARIABLE: [(0, 0)]
4. then it moves to the return statement again which, this time, is executed.

I can't figure out why this is happening. Can you?

As a side note, in case it's helpful, this function is recursive. In this case the return function is invoked after the function has called itself 2 times (each time a tuple gets added to the list, that's why there are 3 tuples)

EDIT: I'm using PyCharm community, latest version (2021.3)

Comment: "execution point moves back to line 1" - why would it?

Comment: We probably need more of your code to determine the issue, but I'm guessing its related to using a list as a default parameter: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/

Comment: I suspect a UI problem with the debugger.  Maybe print something upon entry to the function to see if the function is being entered a second time.

Comment: You **must** provide a [mcve]